# Having trouble directing button to google

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble linking a button to a page using javascript and html. I first add a button to a new page, then call the function. The button displays how I want it to in the new, blank display I created, which won't be shown here. All I need to do is when I click on the button I created, direct open up google.

Here is my javascript code(which isn't working, just posting what I have):

```
function addGoogle() {
            page += "<button>Google Search</button>";
            <button onclick="window.location= 'http://www.google.com';"
        }
```

Here is my html code just in case:

```
     <tr>
        <td> Google</td>
        <td> Google Search</td>
         <td> <button onclick="addGoogle()">Lets Search</button> </td>
    </tr>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want the original button to open google? or the new button added to the page to go to google?

Comment: That's not a valid javascript in your `addGoogle` function.

Comment: the new button added, once i click on it to go to google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you're trying to do.  Looks like you're trying to get one button click to add another button, and then clicking on that second button to go to Google.  If that's the case, the function might need to be something like:

```
function addGoogle() {
            page += "<button onclick=\"window.location='http://www.google.com';\">Google Search</button>";
        }
```

Comment: Yeah, I am clicking the "lets search button" on my html page, then from there, clicking that adds a new button in new, blank webpage, in which I need to be able to click on the new button and be directed to google. I can get everything but direct the new button to google. Any idea?

Comment: I fixed an issue with quotes.  Make sure you got the version with my escaped quotes (required for 3 layers of quoting!  :-)  ).

Answer (score 0):

If all the button does is go to a URL, it should probably be a link. i.e. `<a href="http://example.com">Example link</a>`

Your JavaScript has some invalid JS in it if you wanted to have a button that goes to a link because you have a good reason for it to be a button, then use something like this HTML:

```
<button id="my-button">My button</button>
```

and the following JS

```
var myButton = document.getElementById('my-button');
myButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    window.location.href = 'http://example.com'
});
```

From your question it's not really clear what you want to achieve, but this is probably a close approximate.

Answer (score 0):

That's not the way it's going to work...

You could say:

`<td> <button id="googleButton" onclick="addGoogle()">Let's Search</button> </td>`

Then in your JavaScript you can find the button

```
function addGoogle() {
  window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com'
}
```

Another possibility though is to add a class or id or at least *some* attribute to find your element with JavaScript. There are several ways to find an element (getElementById, querySelector, getElementsByClassName,...). Once you've found your element you can add an event listener to it which listens to the event 'click'. When that event is triggered the code inside the event listener will be triggered.

Because I gave the button an id you could now say:

```
var button = document.getElementById('googleButton');
button.addEventListener('click', function(){
  window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com'
}
```